# How does $|x-{\xi}|<h$ imply that ${\xi}-h<x<{\xi}+h$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

As in title. I don't see how

$|x-{\xi}|<h$

implies that

${\xi}-h<x<{\xi}+h$

I see that $|x-{\xi}|<h$ means that $x<h+{\xi}$ (h is positive), but I don't see what would lead to the second part of the inequality. For the explanation of what the symbols mean, see here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Behaviour_of_Function_Near_Limit

EDIT: Also how to get the result that ${\xi}-h<x<{\xi}+h,x≠ξ$ implies that $-2l<f(x)<0$? My calculations lead to the inequality $2l<f(x)<0$ instead. ${\epsilon}$ is equal to $-l$ this time.

\begin{align}
\ |f(x)-l|<-l
\end{align}

Then we have

\begin{align}
\ f(x)-l<-l \,\,\,\,or\,\,-f(x)+l<-l
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\ f(x)<0 \,\,\,\,or\,\,l-f(x)<-l 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\ f(x)<0 \,\,\,\,or\,\,l+l-f(x)<0 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\ f(x)<0 \,\,\,\,or\,\,2l<f(x)
\end{align}

So now it's $2l<f(x)<0$, without the minus sign.

Comment: If $x>\xi$, then $|x-\xi|=x-\xi$.  If $x<\xi$, then $|x-\xi|=-(x-\xi)$.  Does this help?

Answer (score 2):

$|x-\xi|<h$ means that either $0\le(x-\xi)<h$ or $0\le-(x-\xi)<h$. To get the half of the inequality that you’re missing, note that you can replace the $0$s with $-h$, as the comment below points out.

Comment: One can't combine inequalities in an 'either or' situation. It should be $0\leq x-\xi<h$ or $0\leq\xi-x<h$; in both cases, we can weaken the inequality to $-h < x-\xi < h$.

Comment: Good catch. I shouldn’t post answers when I’m in a hurry.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For $x,y\in\mathbb R,~y\geq 0$ we have: $$|x|<y \Leftrightarrow -y<x<y.$$

Comment: Are you sure that it's $≥$ and not just $>$? After all, if $y=0$, this would mean that $0<x<0$.

Comment: You can change that to $y>0$ if you want to, as it won't make a big difference for your question.

Comment: @Qwedfsf No. If $y=0$, then $|x|<0$ is false as is $0<x<0$. The equivalence stays true.

Answer (score 1):

**(for $h \gt 0$)**. Prove by cases: either (1)  $x \ge \xi$ or (2) $\xi \gt x$

If (1) then $|x - \xi| = x - \xi \lt h$ so $x \lt \xi + h$. Furthermore $x \ge \xi $ so that $x \gt \xi - h$  Putting that together for case (1) gives ${\xi}-h<x<{\xi}+h$.

If (2) then $|x - \xi| = \xi - x \lt h$ so $ \xi - h \lt x$ Furthermore   $\xi \gt x $ so that $x<{\xi}+h$. Putting that together for case (2) gives ${\xi}-h<x<{\xi}+h$.